# Convert String to my desired object

Tags: java, list, string-parsing

I have a list of Attachment type [Attachment is a class which contains some getters and setters].But due to some reasons I need to convert this list to string and after that I have to fetch this list from string.

```
public class Attachment{

    private Integer attachmentCode;

    private String attachmentDesc;
}

Attachment attach1 = new Attachment(); 
Attachment attach2 = new Attachment(); 

List<Attachment> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
tempList.add(attach1);
tempList.add(attach2);

HibernateClass record = new HibernateClass();
record.setValue(tempList .toString());
```

If I want to fetch Attachment object from this String value, how can I achieve my values from this list?

Comment: Did you heard about XML or JSON?

Comment: Where is this string of which you speak?

Comment: You have not shown any examples of the string you want to _parse_.  Without a sample we really cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches I guess. Using XML or JSON or any other textual format would also be a valid approach.

What about using object serialization and Base64 like follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Serialization {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Attachment attach1 = new Attachment();
        Attachment attach2 = new Attachment();

        List<Attachment> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        tempList.add(attach1);
        tempList.add(attach2);

        String value = serialize(tempList);

        List<Attachment> attachments = deserialize(value);
    }

    private static List<Attachment> deserialize(String value) throws Exception {
        byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(value);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decode));
        return (List<Attachment>) ois.readObject();
    }

    private static String serialize(List<Attachment> tempList) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        os.writeObject(tempList);
        byte[] encode = Base64.getEncoder().encode(baos.toByteArray());
        return new String(encode, Charset.defaultCharset());
    }

    private static class Attachment implements Serializable {
        private Integer attachmentCode;
        private String attachmentDesc;
    }

}
```